# SQL order by oldest from Unix Timestamps

Tags: sql, mysql, unix-timestamp

How do I use SQL to order results by oldest first? I am using unix timestamps.

Thanks.

Comment: See you in the year 2038 asking why you've negative timestamps in your DB. Lol.

Comment: I have unsigned integer for my unix timestamp. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The oldest UNIX timestamp is the one that's smallest, so you want to `ORDER BY my_timestamp_column ASC`.

I have no idea why both the answers so far have said to order by the column `DESC`.

Comment: I have to say I have no idea why did I proposed `DESC`... maybe because it's 3 AM, but... ;)

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 3):

> Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds

The ORDER BY clause can use ASC or DESC, if you sepcify none it will default to use ASC:

Most recent time stamps first:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY columnName DESC
```

Less recent time stamps first:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY columnName ASC
```

Comment: UNIX timestamps are seconds since epoch.  The oldest ones have the smallest seconds.  What sort of mass hysteria is causing people to say `DESC` here instead of `ASC`?

Comment: @jemfinch: You're right, I was thinking along the lines of oldest meaning bigger number.  But you are right that an older date is a smaller timestamp.  Corrected.

Comment: Sort of reverse occam's razor: if it's worth asking a question about this, it can't just be a SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY. ...Can it?

Comment: @RJH: You obviously haven't seen some of the questions here.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem you're having using `ORDER BY 'unix-time-stamp-field' ASC;`?

EDIT: `jemfinch` is right, it is `ASC`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get oldest first data when using `unix_timetamp`, run this query:

```
Select * FROM tablename order by FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) ASC
```

here:
ts respond to column of the table which has `unix_timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) clause with `DESC` modifier that reverses the results:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY timestampCol DESC;
```

#### Edit

Of course you should use `ASC` (or none, cause `ASC` is default)... ;)